# Weird scroll behavior when with chrome and smooth scrolling

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll

I'm writing a virtual scrolling lib and encounter a weird problem which only appears in chrome and disable smooth scrolling in chrome flag fix it. One part of the logic is to use an invisible div to stretch the container and when scroll to top, fetch some new data then scroll back to old top. However, in chrome with smooth scrolling, it seems that changes to `scrollTop` will not be applied immediately so multiple data is fetched and scroll position is wrong.

I'm using chrome 84.0.4147.105-1 on Linux and have tested on Windows with same result. It may sometimes be hard to trigger, the safest way is to drag the scrollbar near top without trigger fetching and scroll up. Then you shall find console value jump from 0 to 900(scroll down) to a small number(why?) and trigger fetch again

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container')
const scroller = document.getElementById('scroller')

let height = 0
let isFetching = false
const fetchData = h => {
    if (isFetching) return
    isFetching = true
    setTimeout(() => {
        height += h
        scroller.style.height = height + 'px'
        container.scrollTop += h
        isFetching = false
    }, 50)
}

fetchData(800)

container.addEventListener('scroll', ev => {
    const top = ev.target.scrollTop
    console.log(top)
    if (top <= 50) {
        fetchData(800)
    }
})
```

```css
#container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: auto;
}

#scroller {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
     <div id="scroller"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is really quite an ugly solution. I have been unable to reproduce the exact issue you're seeing, but given that your timeout function will in turn incur additional scrolling events, I wouldn't really expect this to behave reliably

Comment: I have reported to [chrome bugs](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1114732#c_ts1597132736)

Answer (score 0):

A temporary (**and really inelegant**) fix is changing `fetchData` to

```js
const fetchData = h => {
    if (isFetching) return
    isFetching = true
    setTimeout(() => {
        height += h
        scroller.style.height = height + 'px'
        container.scrollTop += h
        isFetching = false
        setTimeout(() => container.scrollTop += h, 200)
    }, 50)
}
```

which scrolls again after a small delay